# Scala Process Builder

Tags: scala

I'm trying to execute a command on Scala, but i'm getting an error

```
s"git --git-dir ${repository.localLocation.get.path}/.git log --format='%h %at %s' --no-decorate" !!
```

I'm getting an error exit status:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 128
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:134)
```

But when i'm running this via terminal it works perfectly:

```
git --git-dir='/var/folders/mk/dc2mnd7x3db1hnqm0vfg6b800000gn/T/XXHMjm7178261334218603127.tmp/.git' log --format='%h %at %s'
```

If i leave only one ***%*** part, it works properly.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the `Seq[String]` variant, because you have space characters in your args that might be used to wrongly separate the arguments. Try

```
Seq("git", "--git-dir", s"${repository.localLocation.get.path}/.git",
  "log", "--format='%h %at %s'", "--no-decorate").!!
```

Also note that you will see the single ticks ' in the output. You probably want `"--format=%h %at %s"`.